Is something wrong with the citation helper?
I've found the citation helper very useful for inserting references in posts, and I always used to be very impressed at its ability to find details of even some quite obscure papers.
But recently it seems to have been frequently failing to find papers that I'd really expect it to find.
Has anybody else noticed this, and if so, does anybody know what's up?
As an example, if I search for one of my own papers with the search terms "Equivalences of derived categories for symmetric algebras Jeremy Rickard", which is the complete title and author, it doesn't find it. This is a 2002 paper (so not ancient, but not recent) in the Journal of Algebra (so far from an obscure journal). Maybe it just has good taste! However, it did find several quite closely related papers, some by me, and at least one that was also in the Journal of Algebra a few years later.

I have also noticed this issue with the citation helper. It sometimes doesn't find a paper even when the title is entered exactly as on zbMATH.

Same here.......

I just retried the example I gave, and now it finds the paper. And other searches that failed recently also seem to work now.
If somebody did something to fix it, then thank you!
